# append python list with only the integer

Tags: python, append

I have the code below, which works, but I want a list of integers only. How do I get python to only append the integer, and not the (array) portion?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

icp4 = np.loadtxt(icp4_img)
ptm = np.loadtxt(ptm_img)

inside, outside = [], []

with np.nditer(icp4, op_flags=['readwrite']) as icp_it, np.nditer(ptm, op_flags=['readonly']) as ptm_it:
    for icp, ptm in zip(icp_it, ptm_it):
        if icp[...] > 800:
            icp[...] = 1
        else:
            icp[...] = 0
        if np.all(icp > 0):
            inside.append(ptm)
        else:
            outside.append(ptm)

p.imshow(icp4, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
p.show()
print(insdie)
>>>[array(435.), array(945.), array(761.)]
```

Comment: adding the ```if ptm.shape == ()``` does not change the output

Answer (score 1):

It appears that each `ptm` is a scalar array.

To obtain the scalar equivalent of a scalar array `ptm`, use `ptm.item()` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html)).

So instead of appending `ptm` to `inside`, try appending `ptm.item()`.

Alternatively, appending `float(ptm)` should accomplish the same task. If this needs to be an integer, append `int(ptm)` instead.

**Remark**

To obtain the scalar equivalent of a scalar array, one used to be able to use `numpy.asscalar()`. However, that function is now deprecated. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html) says to use the `item()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly what you are trying to do, you just need to append `ptm[0]` (i.e the first - and only - integer of the array `ptm`) instead of `ptm`.

Comment: This returns the error: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Comment: Indeed, I did not notice it was a 0-dimensional array.
Appending `int(ptm)` should work.